# Module '"@agm/core"' has no exported member 'Marker' in Angular 14

Tags: angular, agm

I have upgraded to Angular 14 and I am getting the following error:

> Error in turbo_modules/agm-spiderfier@1.0.1/services/google-spider-types.ts (1:10) 
> Module '"@agm/core"' has no exported member 'Marker'.

Here is demo Link :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slqupb?file=src/app/asset-list-map/asset-list-map.module.ts

**Angular version : 14** 
**@agm/core: 3.0.0-beta.0** 
**@agm-spiderfier: 1.0.1** 
**@types/googlemaps: 3.43.3** 
**@agm/js-marker-clusterer: 1.1.0**

I think error in **agm-marker-spider**. If i comment code **import { AgmMarkerSpiderModule } from 'agm-spiderfier';** then map works properly.

Comment: This seems like an issue with the library itself, can you explain what you meant with `If i comment agm-marker-spider map works properly`? Did you remove the package entirely?

Comment: @MikeS. i mean If i comment code `import { AgmMarkerSpiderModule } from 'agm-spiderfier';` then map works properly.

Comment: Looks like the libary is stale and no support for v14 (yet) https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/issues though they are trying to upgrade it: https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/pull/2014